# Creating a script to Import a .csv file to a temp table to create updates to other table within the same database to be ran daily in Oracle SQL Dev

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Can anyone give me an example or syntax on how to use the temptable once it is imported, to loop through the records in the temptable and update other table data based on the temptable row's data.

For reference , See below steps

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable1 
BULK INSERT #tempTable1 from .csv file-- File will in the local folder
--Now from here I would like to do the following:
loop through the #tempTable1 for all records and 
Update table2 
set column1 = 3
set column2 = 0
set column3 = Manually done
set column4 = sysdate
WHERE column5 = #tempTable1 value from column2
AND column2 = 1
AND column1 = 0
AND (column6 in( #tempTable1 value from column1));
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the CSV file located in a folder on your own PC, then **SQL Loader** is *the* utility to be used. It is installed along with any Oracle database or separately as part of the Client software (you'll find all that in Oracle Technology Network's Download section).

SQL Loader is a command-line utility, and it is very fast. It requires you to create a control file which tells Oracle *how* to load source data into a target table within the database. Therefore, you'd create a batch file (if you're on MS Windows) and schedule its execution in Task Manager (as you said you want to run it daily).

You'd also create a .sql script which would perform DML operation once loading is over. You wouldn't do it in a loop - that's slow; use `UPDATE` (or possibly `MERGE`) to do it in a single pass (it'll be much faster than your row-by-row processing). The same batch script would establish connection to the database and call the .sql script.

---

Another option is the **external tables** feature. It requires access to the database server's *directory* (folder) - it would contain the CSV file. You (i.e. your database user) will have to have access to that directory via the Oracle directory object (talk to DBA; they will provide it for you).

You'd then create an external table; basically, CSV file will "act" as if it were an ordinary Oracle table and you can directly access its contents - you don't have to first load it into the database. Therefore, you'd create a **stored procedure** which performs `UPDATE`. As it is *in* the database, you'd then use Oracle's scheduling capabilities, and that's the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package.

---

The 3rd option still requires you to use the Oracle directory, but this time you'd use a stored procedure with the **`UTL_FILE`** package to read CSV file's contents, load data into some table and then `UPDATE` the target table. Just like the previous option, you'd schedule procedure's execution using `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.

---

Now you have 3 different options; pick the one you find the most appropriate.